# Gitlab 8.2.1 '110: Connection timed out' attempting to view merge_request

Tags: nginx, gitlab

We recently upgraded from Gitlab 7.14.0 to Gitlab 8.2.1 on a 16GB/8cpu VM at DigitalOcean. We have one Merge Request with 55 comments that simply won't load in the browser. All other merge_requests load fine. We get the following error from NGINX:

```
2015/12/02 14:49:02 [error] 9094#0: *62 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: gitlab.domain.com, request: "GET /group/project/merge_requests/854 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket/group/project/merge_requests/900", host: "gitlab.domain.com"
```

In config/unicorn.rb we have set `timeout 1200`  (up from an original 30, then tried 300 and 600). 600 was working well with Gitlab 7.14.0. We have `worker_processes 12` also set in config/unicorn.rb.

Gitlab 8.2.1 uses gitlab-workhorse, but I'm not familiar enough with gitlab-workhorse to know if there are settings for it.

Our workhorse settings in Nginx:

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab-workhorse.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

location @gitlab-workhorse {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    proxy_read_timeout      600;
    proxy_connect_timeout   600;
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
}
```

Output from free:

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16433928   11946992    4486936     119052     236972    8130620
-/+ buffers/cache:    3579400   12854528
```

We've restarted Gitlab with `service gitlab restart` in the hopes there was a hungry resource, but we saw no difference.

Any suggestions on how we figure out what is going on and fix this issue?

Comment: if you list "/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets" what do you get?

Comment: ls -la /home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets  
    total 8  
    drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4096 Dec  2 14:59 .  
    drwxr-xr-x 8 git git 4096 Nov 26 22:12 ..  
    -rw-r--r-- 1 git git    0 Aug 21 12:35 .gitkeep  
    srwxrwxrwx 1 git git    0 Dec  2 14:59 gitlab.socket  
    srwxrwxrwx 1 git git    0 Dec  2 14:59 gitlab-workhorse.socket